# How can I keep the tmux prefix key pressed between commands?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

In GNU screen, I can keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> pressed in between commands.

For instance, to change windows I keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> pressed and just keep pressing <kbd>n</kbd> without releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

Is this doable in tmux? Currently I need to release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in between commands.

(By the way, I changed the default prefix from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Holding down <kbd>Control</kbd> to enter multiple Control-modified keys is fairly standard. I am not sure if there is any kind of standard that controls what a terminal will send when you hold <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> while also typing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. The ones I tried are all consistent though: once I press <kbd>N</kbd> they all act as if I had released <kbd>A</kbd> (if ^A was auto-repeating, it stops; if I continue to hold ^N, then it starts to auto-repeat).

If the terminal under which you run *tmux* works similarly to the ones I tried, then you could use this (in your `.tmux.conf`, or directly in *tmux* after <kbd>(your prefix)</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd>):

```
bind-key -r ^N next-window
```

The `-r` gives you 500ms (default, can be changed with the `repeat-time` session option) to press the key again (really, any `-r` flagged, “repeatable” key) without having to press the prefix key again: type your prefix key once, (release it, or not, depending on your terminal), then type any number of “repeatable” keys (as long as they are all within the configured timeout).

If you find yourself releasing both of <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd>, then you might also want to make plain <kbd>N</kbd> repeatable (via `bind-key -r n next-window`) so that both the plain and Control-modified versions are repeatable.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but I've been using it for the last hour and so far does the job, thanks!

Comment: Just starting with tmux.. is setting the repeat-time the only way to accomplish this?  Coming from VIM I'm finding working with this delay to be too flakey.. takes too much finesse instead of working everytime.. do you get used to it?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Inc1982: The `repeat-time` value and the use of the `-r` option in bindings are the only ways to control it that I know of. You can set `repeat-time` to zero to disable the functionality for all repeatable keys, or you could selectively rebind certain keys without the `-r` flag.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to have

`bind-key C-c new-window
bind-key c new-window`

What you are describing is a series of inputs `Ctrl-A, Ctrl-c` as opposed to `Ctrl-a, c` which is what screen does.

From what I've heard (but not absolutely certain), screen has both of these bindings, but since you don't have to specify them in the .rc file, you're not really aware of them.

You should look at some example .tmux.conf files on the web if you want it to act closer to `screen`

Answer (score 2):

The plugin `tmux-sensible` fixes this for me.
https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible

I recommend `tpm` to install it.
https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm#installation
https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible#installation-with-tmux-plugin-manager-recommended

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just created https://github.com/mavenraven/tmux-screen based on the answers for future people who are migrating off screen.